# How to set a value to a data attribute within a script element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="cc-selector col-md-3">
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'home/cart_finish/go'; ?>" class="checkout-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="payment_type" value="omise">
    <script src="https://cdn.omise.co/omise.js.gz"
        data-key="<?php echo $omise_public_key_test; ?>"
        data-image=" "
        data-frame-label="Acme"
        data-button-label="<?php echo translate('pay_now');?>"
        data-submit-label="<?php echo translate('submit');?>"
        data-location="no"
        data-amount=" "
        data-currency="us"
        >

      var total = $('#grand').html();
      $("[data-amount]").attr('data-amount', total);
     </script>  
</form>
```

I want to set a value to the "data-amount" attribute. I tried with the above code, but it doesn't work.

**Note**: Omise is a payment gateway similar to Stripe. That code will render a pay button. I have to had the data-amount set before its render. That's why I cannot wait for the $document to be ready. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: scripts with `src` attribute are not evaluated

Comment: [___If a script element has a `src` attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Ad id to it and use that id with in your code also put your code in another script tag not in that one which call cdn.omise

Comment: What is expected result of setting `data-*` attribute at `<script>` element?

Comment: How is `php` related to Question?

Comment: Please ignore the PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

Append the `<script>` element to `document` without a `src` attribute. At a separate `<script>` element select `script` element and set `data-amount` attribute, and  `src` attribute to path to resource.

```
    <script id="script"
        data-key="<?php echo $omise_public_key_test; ?>"
        data-image=" "
        data-frame-label="Acme"
        data-button-label="<?php echo translate('pay_now');?>"
        data-submit-label="<?php echo translate('submit');?>"
        data-location="no"
        data-amount=" "
        data-currency="us"
        >
     </script>  
     <script>           
     var total = $('#grand').html();
     $("#script[data-amount]")
     .attr({
       "data-amount": total,
       "src":"https://cdn.omise.co/omise.js.gz"
     });
     </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things,

1. If you want to manipulate the script tag, you can't do it from inside itself (as far as my experience has shown).
2. You can't edit the script tag until it exists (is loaded).
3. The button has the data-amount attribute. Can you not just edit that?

```js
$(function(){
        // Button configure will merged and override with default configure.
        // And has effect with this button only.
        OmiseCard.configureButton('button[data-frame-label="Acme"]', {
          amount:           30.95,
          currency:         'thb',
          image:            'YOUR_LOGO_URL',
          frameLabel:       'Merchant name',
          frameDescription: 'Merchant description',
          submitLabel:      'Pay $30.95',
          buttonLabel:      'Pay with Omise',
          location:         'no',
          billingName:      '',
          billingAddress:   '',
          submitFormTarget: null,
        });
        OmiseCard.attach();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="cc-selector col-md-3">
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'home/cart_finish/go'; ?>" class="checkout-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="payment_type" value="omise">
        <script src="https://cdn.omise.co/omise.js.gz"
            data-key="Something"
            data-image=" "
            data-frame-label="Acme"
            data-button-label="Button"
            data-submit-label="Button"
            data-location="no"
            data-amount=" "
            data-currency="us"
            >
         </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. The attribute value needs to be set before the user clicks on the button.

Comment: I have updated the script to reflect your note above about what the omise script is doing

Comment: Still not working. It does set the value, but only after the button is rendered. I need it before.

Comment: From looking at the api on https://www.omise.co/omise-js-api#usage-sample the bottom of the page indicates a method for updating the configuration of a previously configured button. I have included all the value in the example in my snippet but you could likely just use the amount value to update the button as needed.